# using I2C in threads

Tags: i2c, pigpio

I have several devices on one I2C Bus and am wondering now what happens, if I have some threads using this one I2C Bus. Do I need to implement a scheduler or is the I2C Bus automatically blocked between a i2cOpen() and i2cClose()?

Comment: I wonder if the author (@joan) can be summoned by mentioning him in a comment

Comment: It should work unless you are sending more than one command to the same I²C device. The I²C is a parallel bus with each device having a unique read address and a complimentary write address.